# select query - each two row into single result row

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Lets assume I have the following 'Products' table:

```
ProductID | ProductName 
----------+---------
0255463   | ProductA       
0254483   | ProductB
0255341   | ProductC
0905454   | ProductD
```

Is there a way (in Android's SQLite) to select each two consecutive rows into single result row?
Here is the desired query result:

```
FirstProductID | FirstProductName | SecondProductID | SecondProductName 
---------------+------------------+-----------------+---------
0255463        | ProductA         |        0254483  | ProductB
0255341        | ProductC         |       0905454   | ProductD
```

I would like a generic solution that can be used to any table, regardless the table content.

Comment: Data representation should be handled at an application (PHP) level

Comment: You are absolutely right. 
However, I need it for an android application (I'm using their built-in SqlLite) in order to use a Cursor Loader. In case I would like to get 2 items in one ListView item this is the only solution since the Loader is tightly bound to the list adapter. in other words: a cursor its the only input I can use in order to populate an android list view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a temporary table with an auto increment column

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp(
  id int not null primary auto increment,
  pid int,
  pname text,    
);
```

Insert select this data into the temporary table

```
INSERT INTO temp (pid, pname) SELECT * FROM Products;
```

Join the temporary table on `id = id + 1` where the first instance has `id % 2 = 0`

```
SELECT t1.pid AS t1_pid, t1.pname AS t1_pname,
  t2.pid AS t2_pid, t2.pname AS t2_pname
FROM temp as t1 LEFT JOIN temp AS t2
  ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t1.id % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: @LS_dev, thanks for the edits, I didn't have a mysql environment handy to try that out.  I wonder if there's any commercial value in emulating a mysql session in the browser for tutorials.

Comment: This question is about [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), which has a free, easy and lightweight command-line shell.

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) seems to be the common solution on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Single query (not faster):

```
SELECT
    First.ProductId AS FirstProductId,
    First.ProductName AS FirstProductName,
    Second.ProductId AS SecondProductId,
    Second.ProductName AS SecondProductName 
FROM
    (SELECT *, Cnt/2 AS Line FROM (
        SELECT *, (
            SELECT COUNT() FROM Products AS _ WHERE ROWID<Products.ROWID
        ) AS Cnt FROM Products WHERE Cnt%2=0
    )) AS First
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *, Cnt/2 AS Line FROM (
        SELECT *, (
            SELECT COUNT() FROM Products AS _ WHERE ROWID<Products.ROWID
        ) AS Cnt FROM Products WHERE Cnt%2=1
    )) AS Second
ON First.Line = Second.Line
ORDER BY First.Line;
```

If you need a faster solution, @kzarns proposed a good one.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you have consecutive IDs for the rows:

```
SELECT t1.productID AS productID1, t1.ProductName AS productName1, t2.productID AS productID2, t2.ProductName AS ProductName2
FROM product t1
JOIN product t2 WHERE t1.id+1 = t2.id
WHERE MOD(t1.id,2) = 1
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample idea , basically what am i doing is obtain different result from 2 select statement and join it , have a try on it, cheer =)

--sample table

```
DECLARE @SAMPLE TABLE
(
ProductID INT,
ProductName NVARCHAR(255)
)
```

--sample data

```
INSERT INTO @SAMPLE
VALUES
('1','ProductA'),
('2','ProductB'),
('3','ProductC'),
('4','ProductD')

SELECT FirstProductID,FirstProductName,SecondProductID,SecondProductName FROM
(
```

--Query to get firstProduct items

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstProductID) firstrn,FirstProductID,FirstProductName
FROM(
SELECT ProductID 'FirstProductID',ProductName 'FirstProductName' FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by productid) firstrn1,ProductID,ProductName
FROM @SAMPLE
) FIRSTPRODUCTTABLE
WHERE firstrn1%2 = 1
) FIRSTPRODUCTTABLE1 
)t1
```

-A join is performed

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
```

--Query to get second product items

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SecondProductID) rownumber,SecondProductID,SecondProductName
FROM(
SELECT ProductID 'SecondProductID',ProductName 'SecondProductName' FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by productid) rn,ProductID,ProductName
FROM @SAMPLE
) SECONDPRODUCTTABLE
WHERE rn%2 = 0
)SECONDPRODUCTTABLE1
) t2
) t3 ON t1.firstrn=t3.rownumber
```

Comment: This is not [tag:SQLite]!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in SQL would be rather complex and slow.

The cleanest way to reorder column values like this would be to implement your own [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) class that wraps the original database cursor, but doubles the number of columns, and redirects all column accesses to the appropriate record.
Something like this:

```java
class DoubleColumnCursor implements Cursor {
    Cursor baseCursor;
    int baseColumns;
    int currentPosition;

    public getColumnCount() {
        return baseColumns * 2;
    }
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex < baseColumns)
            return baseCursor.getColumnName(columnIndex) + "1";
        else
            return baseCursor.getColumnName(columnIndex - baseColumns) + "2";
    }
    public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        boolean result = baseCursor.moveToPosition(position * 2);
        if (result)
            currentPosition = position;
        return result;
    }
    public String getString(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex < baseColumns) {
            baseCursor.moveToPosition(currentPosition * 2);
            return baseCursor.getString(columnIndex);
        } else {
            baseCursor.moveToPosition(currentPosition * 2 + 1);
            return baseCursor.getString(columnIndex - baseColumns);
        }
    }
    ...
};
```